# Was Geocoder successful?

Tags: geokit, rails-geocoder

Geokit has the helpful functionality:

```
g = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode [address_1, address_2, city, zip_code, state, country].compact.join(', ')
if g.success == true
  ...
```

Can the Geocoder gem return a `true` somehow if Google successfully geocoded the address given?